# kendo ui grid sortable and crud is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have followed this tutorial and brought up the sorting to work but now the crud operation is not working.

If i remove the grid sortable code then the crud is working, but no sort.
I have no idea where i am making mistake to make both sort and crud to work

THis is the code i have

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                function dataSource_change(e) {
                  var data = this.data();
                  console.log(data.length); // displays "77"
                }
                var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                   //pageSize: 20,
                  transport:{
                      read:{
                        url: function() {
                          return "/makes"},
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false
                      },
                      update: {
                        url: function (make) {
                        console.log(make)

                        return  "/makes/"+ make.models[0].id
                        },
                        type: "PUT",
                        dataType: "json",
                        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")); }
                      },
                      destroy: {
                          url: function (make) {
                            return  "/makes/"+ make.models[0].id
                          },
                          type: "DELETE",
                          dataType: "json"
                      },
                      create: {
                          url: "/makes",
                          type: "POST",
                          dataType: "json"
                      },
                      parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                      if (operation !== "read"  && options.models) {
                        console.log(options)
                        return{"make": options.models[0]};
                      }
                      else{
                        return {"make":options};
                        }
                      }
                  },
                  batch: true,
                   schema: {
                       model: {
                         id: "id",
                         fields: {
                            id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            name: { validation: { required: true } },
                         }
                       }
                   }
                });
                dataSource.bind("change", dataSource_change);
                dataSource.fetch();

                var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    pageable: false,
                    height: 550,
                    toolbar: [{name: "create", text: "Add New Make"}],
                    columns: [
                        { field:"name",title:"Makes" },                                      
                        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Action", width: "250px" }],
                    editable: "inline"
                }).data("kendoGrid");
                grid.table.kendoSortable({
                    filter: ">tbody >tr",
                    hint: $.noop,
                    cursor: "move",
                    placeholder: function(element) {
                        return element.clone().addClass("k-state-hover").css("opacity", 0.65);
                    },
                    container: "#grid tbody",
                    change: function(e) {
                        console.log(grid)
                        var skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
                            oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
                            newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
                            data = grid.dataSource.data(),
                            dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));
                        var updated_order = []
                        $('tbody tr').each(function(i){
                          updated_order.push({ name: $(this).children('td:first').text(), position: i+1 });
                        });
                        controller_name = $('#controller_name').val();
                        $.ajax({
                          type: "PUT",
                          url: '/sort',
                          data: { order: updated_order, controller_name: controller_name }
                        });

                        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
                        grid.dataSource.insert(e.newIndex, dataItem);
                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: Can you try to remove that ajax call from sortable event to see if it works. Then debug that for some errors, because without that part you can see it working here: http://dojo.telerik.com/EdIlE

Comment: @calinaadi Even after removing ajax it is not working the params are going  empty for me. Previously params going empty i forgot to mention it

Comment: How about providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).